# pair value comparison to generate new raster using arcpy/python

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python, arcpy, python-2.6

I want to write a function which takes in two arguments (from two rasters) and compare those 2 values against a set of hard coded pair values inside function. Then return a value which i want to use to generate a new grid. I am not quite there to complete the function. Any suggestions?

```py
def grid(val1, val2):
    table = {'10','1':'75','10,2':'75','10,3':'83','10,4':'87'}
    for i, j, k in table.iteritems():
        if val1 == i:
            if val2 == j:
                val = k
    return val

t = grid(10,1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to fairly easily [grab your raster as a numpy array](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v0000012z000000) in ArcGIS (and for that matter [put it back](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/NumPyArrayToRaster/000v00000130000000/)).

Then borrow liberally from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3404089) to this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403973/fast-replacement-of-values-in-a-numpy-array).

In your case you have two grids, each with their own corresponding value. Tuples can act as a dictionary key, so that's what I'd suggest in your case. Then we have a simple bit of code:

```py
#grid_1 and grid_2 are numpy arrays of the input rasters
import numpy as np

table = {(10, 1):75,
         (10, 2):75,
         (10, 3):83,
         (10, 4):87}

#assuming that the input grids are the same dimensions
output_grid = np.ones(grid_1.shape, dtype=np.int) * -9999 #usually a good value for null

for k, v in table.iteritems(): #k will be a tuple
    output_grid[[grid_1 == k[0]] and [grid_2 == k[1]]] = v
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried to test it with simple 10 and 1 value and got following error:

TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment

at:
`grid_1[grid_1==k[0]] = v`

Comment: Sorry; `grid_1` should be the entire raster as a numpy array (this will replace every instance of the number in the grid with the value from `table`)

Comment: Sorry, re-read the question; given you want a different grid as output I've modified the function above to return a separate grid.

Comment: It worked. 
I tried to save the final grid but got following error:

`ValueError: Argument in_array: Array type is not supported.`

`outgrid = np.ones(lu.shape, dtype=np.int) * -9999
for k,v in table.iteritems():
    outgrid[[grid1 == k[0]] and [grid2 == k[1]]] = v
    print outgrid
    myArray = arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster(outgrid)
    myArray.save("grid3")`

Comment: -9999 caused that problem while saving numpy array as raster. Anyhow I checked the result and there is something wrong with how iteration is done. I used a full table with 40 records but final output only have 4 integer values. I am still trying to understand whether it is caused by 'iteritems' or tuple comparison.

Comment: Couple of questions that might help: what data type is your raster? Also, could you post a sample of the table you're using? In your code above with the four keys you gave you would only expect three different integers as output.

Comment: use of binary AND operator instead of logical AND solved the problem. Thanks for your help all the way.